# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100, Beginner Project

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

So im working on this project for class and I am to read a text file called "randomNumbers" store it in an array and print it out to the screen. It complies fine but when I run the code I get

```
enter code here
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
at projectFour.read_file(projectFour.java:32)
at projectFour.main(projectFour.java:13)
```

Iv tried to the best of my ability to solve it but I am stuck.

Here is the code I have thus far,

```
enter code here import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class projectFour
{
public static int [] global_numbers;


public static void main (String[] args)
{
  read_file();
  print_numbers(global_numbers);

}



public static void read_file()
{
try
      {
        File file = new File("randomNumbers.txt"); 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        int maxNumberInFile = convertingStringToInt(scan.nextLine()); // read the first line which is 100 to set array size
        global_numbers = new int[maxNumberInFile]; // set the array size equal to the first line read which is 100
        int i = 0; 

             while(scan.hasNextLine()) // while there is a next line to read, do this...
              {
                 String line = scan.nextLine();
                 global_numbers [i] = convertingStringToInt(line); 
                 i++; 
              }
                 scan.close();        
      }

  catch(IOException ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }    

}

public static int convertingStringToInt(String number)
{  
try
     {
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
     }

  catch(NumberFormatException n)
     {
           return -460;
     }         
}

public static void print_numbers(int [] numbers)
{
  int max = numbers.length;
  for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
     {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]); 
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

The `code` you have posted works perfectly without errors.

You just **have** to make sure that the number of lines (excluding the first line) is (100).

To prove that test it on a small scale for example:

Put this in `randomNumbers.txt`

```
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there're more than 100 numbers in your file. If you only want to read 100 numbers, you can:

```
public static void read_file()
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File("randomNumbers.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        int maxNumberInFile = convertingStringToInt(scan.nextLine());   // read the first line which is 100 to set array size
        global_numbers = new int[maxNumberInFile]; // set the array size equal to the first line read which is 100
        int i = 0;

        //while(scan.hasNextLine()) // while there is a next line to read, do this...
        while (i < maxNumberInFile)
        {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            global_numbers [i] = convertingStringToInt(line);
            i++;
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If you don't know how many numbers in the file exactly, you can use a List to store the numbers.

Comment: okay yeah thats what I thought. I came up with a for loop. now my problem is all my reutrn values are -460 so my converting string to int method isnt working....

Comment: You can print the string to see if it's a valid int before convert it to int. Maybe the string contains some other characters?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it is now reading the file, however in my convertingToStringMethod there is something not right as all the output values are -460, except the very last number in the file is read....

```
enter code here
  public static int convertingStringToInt(String numbers) //what does string       number equal? why/where is it declared?
 {  
  try
     {
        return Integer.parseInt(numbers);
     }

  catch(NumberFormatException n)
     {
           return -460;
     }         
}
```